# Paging in GIT when adding untracked files

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm trying to view all of the results of my git -add -i -> 'add untracked' but I am unable to view the first few results. I know that there is a paging function inside of git but I cannot seem to find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: This *seems* pretty clearly to be asking about the `git status` sub-command in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

You can pipe any Git command to a pager program like `less`:

```
git status | less
```

This tho won't preserve any text colors that Git (might) normally output.

The second way to do this is to use one of the two pagination options for the `git` command. To use a specific pager command:

```
git --pager=<pager command> status
```

or to use the default Git pager command:

```
git --paginate status
```